# ngx-toastr memory leak timeout

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

I have a memory leak issue in my application somewhere and I have code all over my project that looks like this

```
this.toastr.success("message sent!", "", {
                    timeOut: 2000
                  });
```

instead of

```
 this.timeout = this.toastr.success("message sent!", "", {
                    timeOut: 2000



  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }
```

and I was wondering if not assigning this.timeout to the toast so that I can clear it could be causing the memory leak?

Comment: I would open an issue at https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues

Comment: I'm not saying it's causing a memory leak. I'm not sure if it is. I'm asking if I need to assign this.timeout to it and then ```ngOnDestroy()``` to it as well or will it cause a memory leak? Or is that unneccessary and ```timeOut``` will clear itself from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts and clearing intervals and timeouts are handled in the [toast.component.ts](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/master/src/lib/toastr/toast.component.ts#L123).

So no, the library takes care of that.